# Fixing performance decrease using double wrapper class for bit manipulations (C++, clang)

Tags: c++, boost, clang

The question I have is "Can I write a bitset-type class which can both be used with an internal unsigned and dynamic_bitset internal representation without losing the performance of an exclusive unsigned bitset class?"

To give some context, I'm trying to create a class which acts as a bitset where frequent manipulation that I require are implemented. First draft of this class uses an unsigned long representation internally.

However I need to go beyond 64 or 128 bits in some cases and this would require the use of either boost's dynamic bitset, or an array of unsigned longs as an internal representation.

Now, my first draft is as performant as the code that would simply use a naked unsigned long (using the -O3 flag for my compiler). And I fully realise that I'm not able to maintain this performance in the case of using a dynamic bitset. However I would like to only write my algorithms once, using my class, instead of writing one code with unsigned representation and one using dynamic bitset. So I created a bitsetwrapper Class which has a pointer to an abstract bitset which can either be the bitset with the internal unsigned long bitset or a bitset with an internal dynamic bitset. Which derived class it shall point to is then decided by the amount of bits you need to use.

This way the I never have to worry about using pointers to abstract classes as these are confined in my wrapper. An example:

```
    class BitsetBase{}
    class UnsignedBitset : public BitsetBase{
            unsigned long representation;
    }
    class DynamicBitsetBitset : public BitsetBase{
            dynamic_bitset<> representation;
    }

    class BitsetWrapper{
        *BitsetBase bitset;
    }
```

Now I've run into some performance issues which I have so far failed to fix completely.

Initial performance benchmarks are as follows (relative comparison):

```
    Unsinged long code : 1s
    UnsingedBitset code : 1s
    BitsetWrapper code (using UnsingedBitset) : 4s
```

To give you some extra context, many copies are being made in all 3 instances. This is what causes the increase in the BitsetWrapper to 4s. Because in my initial attempt I used "new" to initialise Bitset instances.

Now I managed to circumvent new completely by initialising UnsingedBitset externally and passing them as an argument for my wrapper constructor.
Yielding a significant performance increase.

```
    Unsinged long code : 1s
    UnsingedBitset code : 1s
    BitsetWrapper code (using UnsingedBitset) : 2.4s
```

However it is vital to reach the 1s performance. I'm quite surprised that the UnsignedBitset version has the same performance as the raw Unsigned long code. My guess is that the compiler can optimise it in someway, but can no longer do that for the "double" wrapper. Does anyone have an idea why the performance is so much worse, and if there is an other way to fix my issues? (ps. I've also tried boost::variant this is also 3 times slower)

Code example:

```
    for(1000000 loops){                
        AnyClass bitset(random_input) 
        while(!bitset.equalsZero()){
            bitset.removeLeastSignificantBit()
            AnyClass bitset2 = bitset
            bitset2.invert()
            while(!bitset2.equalsZero()){
                result += bitset2.someManipulation();
            }
        }
    }
```

To ask the question more clearly. Is it possible for me to create a wrapper around a representation which can internally chose which representation it should use (based on some parameter) without losing performance if the internal representation is unsigned long compared to the wrapper with a fixed unsigned long representation.

Example of a code called is :

```
    void invert(){
            representation = ~representation;
    )
```

(no performance loss)
Which would then become:

```
   void invert(){
       bitset_instance->invert();
   }
```

in the Bitset wrapper (performance loss).

Comment: What about `std::bitset`? It is not dynamical, but certainly can hold more than 128 bits

Comment: Impossible to tell you anything about why your code is not performing as you wish - you haven't shown it or your benchmarks.

Comment: I've added some extra context, the vital part of the question is, can I write a class which can interchangeably be used with an internal unsigned and dynamic_bitset without losing the performance of an exclusive unsigned class.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing more code, I can only speculate, but it's possible that the cost of the virtual function calls and the indirection outweighs the cost of bit operations. This may especially be imaginable if every bit flip is done through a virtual function call. This is most likely, since you eliminated allocations as an extra performance overhead – but again, for certainty one would need to know more about your usage pattern.

Do you really need the flexibility? If you want to remove the abstraction, there are some possibilities:

1. Use `dynamic_bitset` all the time.
2. Use another implementation, such as `std::vector<bool>` (most likely not more performant than 1)
3. Use a different dispatch mechanism. If you know the cases at compile time, templates are an obvious option. Other runtime mechanisms (if/else, switch) yield most likely around the same performance as virtual functions.

P.S. Not sure if it's just omitted for brevity, but polymorphic base classes should have a virtual destructor. This is even good practice, if you allocate them on the stack and just pass around pointers.

Comment: So my "simple" wrapper does not lose performance
only when I put that wrapper into the wrapper does which simply passes the function call do I lose performance.

Example of such a function is now added to my post.

Comment: Using only dynamic bitset will never be the case, my final option would simply be writing it once for unsigned longs and then write the algorithm again with dynamic_bitset.